Solr returning 404 after startup when sending update request
After Solr startup and creating collections, I'm waiting for collection to become active by sending request to http://localhost:8984/api/collections/, checking state and health. However even if health and status are correct, first requests to solr//update/json returns 404. It can be "solved" by adding some waiting time after collections are up, but I'm looking for a way to do it without unnecessary wait.
